# How to display y-axis value in series

Tags: charts, highcharts

I need to display y-values in series means (36, 37, 38, 39, 40 .......) y-axis values start from 36 to 165  but they're in series but some numbers are missing. Even I have added this options in highchart

```
yAxis: { 
          title: {
              text: 'Channel Count',
              style: {
                  color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
              }
          },
          min: 36,
          max: 165,
          opposite: false,
      }
```

But still not working. So how can I display them in series?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create space for ticks by increasing the height of the chart:

```
chart: {
    height: 2000
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xrkh7q89/

Or use `tickPositioner` function:

```
    tickPositioner: function(){
        var positions = [];

        for (var i = 36; i < 166; i++){
            positions.push(i);
        }
        return positions
    }
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qx8m97g4/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPositioner

Comment: Thanks @ppotaczek you saved my day.